# Multiple buttons on navigation bar

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am using code from http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html to implement multiple buttons in the navigation bar.

The huge problem I have now is that this construction "leaks" into the main window. By this I mean that if I press (up to about 15px) below the navigation bar the buttons still respond. How can I fix this?

Or does someone have a better way to implement multiple buttons?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that your button bounds are extending beyond the navbar bounds. You can confirm this by setting the color of the button to something other than clear. To fix this you can either fix the frame of the buttons, or make sure `clipsToBounds` property of the containing view is set to `YES`.